# Do i always need to start the new site in django by "django-admin"

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When i need to start new django i use   `django-admin startproject  site1` and it then create skeltion files.

Then use `syncdb`

i want to know if just copy the files from previous site e,g site1 and then rename it to different folder and make necessary chnages in settings and URL and then use syncdb . Will my site work or

I have to use `startproject` always and it does some database inserting other than making skelton files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to use `startproject`.  You can copy files from another project or write the skeleton files yourself.  You probably want to have a unique `SECRET_KEY` setting though.

Comment: What the use of that SECRET_KEY . If i use same key what will happen

Comment: SECRET_KEY is just a seed for random hashing algorithms. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs

Comment: If it's in multiple of your own projects deployed on the same server, then it might not be a problem.  However, if you ship the settings to a customer, you should make sure that key is not used again.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can definitely copy (or clone with `mercurial`, `git`, you name it) your project and make necessary changes and you are done.

Django-admin is just a nice utility to make your **django** development easier, but it doesn't setup or do anything ultra-special on your project location.